# How to achieve something like strftime but with rtp frame timstamp

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record a rtsp stream with ffmpeg, segmented by certain amount of time, and name the file with the start time. I used strftime to expand the output filename with timestamp, but I wonder if there is an option that can expand the filename with rtp timestamp instead of local time.

Below is my current ffmpeg command

> ffmpeg -y -i url -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format mp4
> -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1  -acodec copy -vcodec copy ./%Y/%m/%d/%H/record_%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.mp4